# Volume slide = 0 if clicked on 'mute'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Well, the title says it all.

I managed to connect it when you slide the volume to 0 it's muted, but now I'm having problems with makaking it like this: if muted the volume slider should be at 0.

I tried some combinations of code, but can't seem to get my head around it.

html:

```html
     <div class="controls">
              <span class="columns small-8 medium-6 text-left">
                <span *ngIf="!playing" class="playpause" (click)="videoHandler('play')">
                  <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                </span>
                <span *ngIf="playing" class="playpause" (click)="videoHandler('pause')">
                  <i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                </span>
                <span *ngIf="!muted" class="speaker" (click)="videoHandler('mute')">
                  <i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                </span>
                <span *ngIf="muted" class="speaker" (click)="videoHandler('unmute')">
                  <i class="fa fa-volume-off" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                </span>
                <span class="volumeslider">
                  <input type="range" name="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1" (input)="videoHandler('volume', $event)">
                </span>
              </span>
            </div>
```

typescript:

```js
public videoHandler(fn: any, e: any): void {
    let element = this.videoplayer.nativeElement;

    switch (fn) {
        case 'play':
            element.play();
            this.playing = true;
            break;
        case 'pause':
            element.pause();
            this.playing = false;
            break;
        case 'fullscreen':
            if (element.requestFullscreen) {
                element.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                element.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            }
            break;
        case 'mute':
            element.muted = true;
            this.muted = true;
            break;
        case 'unmute':
            element.muted = false;
            element.removeAttribute('muted');
            this.muted = false;
            break;
        case 'volume':
            element.volume = e.target.value;
            this.muted = e.target.value === '0';
            element.muted = e.target.value === '0';
            break;
        case 'download':
            let src = e.target.dataset.vsr;
            let id = e.target.dataset.vid;
            this.downloadEmitter.emit({
                video: src,
                video_id: id
            });
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

For sure it's simple, but looking at this for a few days doesn't let me get to new ideas.

Comment: It looks like your code wants to have seven separate functions instead of one, but you're merging them so that you don't need to repeat the first line. You want ```const volume 
 = document.querySelector('[name="volume"]'); volume.setAttribute("--unmute", volume.value); volume.value = 0;``` in your mute function and ```const volume = document.querySelector('[name="volume"]'); const unmuteValue = volume.getAttribute("--unmute"); volume.value = unmuteValue ? unmuteValue : 0;``` in your unmute function. Or something along those lines.

Comment: @Charles Bamford thank you for your replay! I tried your idea and tried to adapt it, but this doesn't work, it seems like it won't accept the value of volume to be 0 :/

Answer (score 0):

If you'll ever need this, the answer was so simple, I'll post the code here:

```
 <div class="controls">
          <span class="columns small-8 medium-6 text-left">
            <span *ngIf="!playing" class="playpause" (click)="videoHandler('play')">
              <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="playing" class="playpause" (click)="videoHandler('pause')">
              <i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="!muted" class="speaker" (click)="videoHandler('mute'); slider.value = 0" >
              <i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="muted" class="speaker" (click)="videoHandler('unmute'); slider.value = 1">
              <i class="fa fa-volume-off" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
            </span>
            <span class="volumeslider">
              <input type="range" name="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1" (input)="videoHandler('volume', $event); slider.value = $event.target.value" class="volumeslide" #slider>
            </span>
          </span>
   </div>
```

So what I missed was adding `slider.value = number` to mute or unmute.